# How does one log in to mark a question as answered if the Name/Email post question method was used

Tags: support, accepting, login

I asked the question 
[What is a suitable package for drawing term algebra style trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52172/what-is-a-suitable-package-for-drawing-term-algebra-style-trees) and signed in using the Name/Email method.  I guess, for some reason, I thought it would log me in.  However, now the question has been answered, and I have no idea how to log in and mark it as answered.  I was able to post until I logged in to this account.

Answer (score 7):

Your question was posted using an unregistered account and was not connected to your registered one. Either your browser session of this question post expired or it is because you used two different email addresses.

Anyway, in such cases users should flag the question for moderator attention using the gray 'flag' link below it. You can then state there that you want to have both accounts merged.

I already merged your two together, keeping your real name from the unregistered account (your can edit this if you want). It will take a few minutes until your meta account is synchronized with your (real) account on the main site.